# Spring Boot dependency injection sets object of childClass instead of parent Class

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I am trying to implement the factory design pattern which returns different class object based on argument. I need parent class object for one argument and child class for another.
parent class is extending one abstract class which in turn implementing the interface.

I am passing the argument for parent class. But the object returned by factory is of childClass. I tried to debug and found that when factory constructor is called the object passed in parent class variable is of child class only. I am not able to rectify how same is happening and how to resolve the same.
I also used lomboks @requiredArgsConstructor on factory to no avail.

Here is sudo code for same. I am using Junit testing to test my code before going further with application testing
spring-boot.version :- 2.3.9.RELEASE
JDK :- 1.8

```
public interface Interface {
   
}
```

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public abstract class AbstractClass implements Interface{

}
```

```
@Slf4j
@Component("ParentClass")
public class ParentClass extends AbstractClass {

}
```

```
@Slf4j
@Component("ChildClass")
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
}
```

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class Factory {

    private final ParentClass parentClass;
    private final ChildClass childClass;

    Factory(@Qualifier("ParentClass") ParentClass parentClass,@Qualifier("ChildClass") ChildClass childClass) {
      
        this.ParentClass = parentClass;
        this.ChildClass = childClass;
    }
     
    public Interface getObject(boolean isParent){
            if(isParent)
                return parentClass;
            else
                return childClass;
    
    }
}
```

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FactoryTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private Factory factory;
    
    @Mock
    private ParentClass parentClass;
    @Mock
    private ChildClass childClass;
    
    @Test
    public void getObjectTest() {
       
        assertEquals(parentClass, factory.getObject(true));

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you testing your code only be using the above test class?

Comment: @Ismail Yes as of now. I thought it would be better idea to test using junit first

Comment: In your test case, the spring context is not active, your are only mocking the dependencies using Mockito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test doesn't "turn on spring magic". As correctly pointed out in the comments, you need to activate the spring context.

What's currently happening is that mockito takes the first suitable candidate to be injected into the Factory object. `@Qualifier` just doesn't play any role in this case. You can take a look here at how mockito does it: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/87a99dd87a4b1ca1ed356c4bd691bf01f8efec77/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/configuration/injection/ConstructorInjection.java#L81. You can prove it as well by moving `@Mock` fields in your factory - you'll have different result for your test.

In order to turn on the spring test context and its features in your test, you can for example annotate it with `@SpringBootTest` and `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`. Then you don't need to mock anything, you can just autowire everything.

```java
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class FactoryTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ChildClass")
    private ChildClass childClass;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ParentClass")
    private ParentClass parentClass;

    @Autowired
    private Factory factory;

    @Test
    public void getObjectTest() {
        assertEquals(parentClass, factory.getObject(true));
        assertEquals(childClass, factory.getObject(false));
    }
}
```

Another option without spring context is to create Factory object yourself, without `@InjectMocks`. For example, like this:

```java
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FactoryTest {

    @Mock(name = "childClass")
    private ChildClass childClass;

    @Mock(name = "parentClass")
    private ParentClass parentClass;

    private Factory factory;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        factory = new Factory(parentClass, childClass);
    }

    @Test
    public void getObjectTest() {
        assertEquals(parentClass, factory.getObject(true));
        assertEquals(childClass, factory.getObject(false));

    }
}
```